# Element prototype exceptions (not a function or method)

Tags: javascript, dom, mootools

whatever i append to $('click_filter1') it shows the error ... is not a function (for show(), hide(), toggle())

if i insert an alert, the alert gets executed, so the framework is init ok

the element with the id exists for sure

what can be the problem of this? why iam getting this error?

```
    $('click_filter1').addEvent('click', function() {
        $('click_filter1').show();
    }.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your title is misleading and not descriptive enough.

Secondly, `toggle`, `show`, `hide` for `Element` is only available when you include `Element.Shortcuts` from [MooTools-more](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Element/Element.Shortcuts) - be sure to do that, and the code will work as expected.

Working example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/UjF2y/

Comment: +1. @adriane also, you may want to pass on the event object and then use e.target.method to save an extra lookup. actually, how do you click on an invisible element that is not shown before you do so or is this pseudo code? :)